# If you type in a command, how to add a new text while keeping the old text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am basically trying to keep the old text and while if you type in help it add a new line of text. the problem is the every time I type in help it prints the old text again (twice) and then prints the new text.

```
     public Canvas myCanvas;
     public Text myText;

     private string display = "";

     List<string> chatEvents;

     private bool calltext;

     public InputField inputfield;
     private Dictionary<string, System.Action<string,string>> commands;

     protected void Awake()
     {
         commands = new Dictionary<string, System.Action<string,string>>();
         // Add the commands you want to recognise along with the functions to call
         commands.Add( "help", OnHelpTyped );
         // Listen when the inputfield is validated
         inputfield.onEndEdit.AddListener( OnEndEdit );
     }

     private void OnEndEdit( string input )
     {
         // Only consider onEndEdit if the Submit button has been pressed
         if ( !Input.GetButtonDown( "Submit" ) )
             return;

         bool commandFound = false;

         // Find the command
         foreach ( var item in commands )
         {
             if ( item.Key.ToLower().StartsWith( input.ToLower() ) )
             {
                 commandFound = true;
                 item.Value( item.Key, input );
                 break;
             }
         }

         // Do something if the command has not been found
         if ( !commandFound )
             Debug.Log( "No word found" );

         // Clear the input field (if you want)
         inputfield.text = "";
     }

     private void OnHelpTyped( string command, string input )
     {
         chatEvents.Add ("The List");
         calltext = true;
     }

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         chatEvents = new List<string>();

         chatEvents.Add("Welcome to my simple application ");
         chatEvents.Add ("Type help for list of commands");

         calltext = true;

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         if(calltext)
         {
             AddText();
             calltext = false;
         }
     }

     void AddText()
     {
         foreach(string msg in chatEvents)
         {
             display = display.ToString () + msg.ToString() + "\n";
         }
         myText.text = display;
     }
 }
```

Here is the image before and after

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmRij.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k4bS.png)

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the-same question? Why not read the answers + plus comments in your other questions then apply it to whatever you are doing?

Comment: Hey look I am sorry for asking the same question but the other question didn't really help me so I figure out how to do it but there  this problem, that is not really related to the other question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you never clear your `chatEvents` list so each time you call `AddText` you itterate through all the strings in `chatEvents` and add them again.